# Windows services automation tests (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-services, automated-tests

I want to create automation tests for few windows services. Services communicates with each other over Tcp/Ip sockets. One service is responsible of writing/reading to/from database. It is some kind of micro service architecture solution. I have a lot of unit tests, but I also want to test all service(some test case, performace) not a part of it. Maybe someone have any experience or ideas how to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a lot of unit tests already, and if the unit tests are designed appropriately (not just "code coverage", but unit feature coverage), then your overall test can be Feature or behaviour style black box testing.

You can create another solution with Specflow tests on there and without mocking anything, test the top level entry points of those services that are accessible to the "external" users/services. In there, you will implement your step definitions to interact with your services the same way as those external users/services will be doing. It could be over TCP/IP sockets, HttpRequests or using a browser.. up to you.

Hope it helps